# python change position and shift other element

Tags: python, list

I have the below list :-

```
someList = ["one","three","four","five","six","two"]
```

I want to change position of "two" i.e after "one" and rest string should be shifted as they are.

Expected Output : -

> someList = ["one","two","three","four","five","six",]

Answer (score 2):

You can pop 2 from current index and insert to new index

```py
l.insert(1, l.pop(-1))
```

Comment: `l.pop()` and `l.pop(-1)` same

Comment: can I pop with like l.pop("two")

Comment: "two" position not fixed

Comment: No but you can get index by running l.index(“two”)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking to redistribute

```
a,c,d,e,b = ["one","three","four","five","six","two"]
someList= [a,b,c,d,e]
someList
```